# get name of the day in local language

Tags: php, date

I need the name of the day in a local (serbian) language.

```
$date = date_create();
$day = date_format($date,"l");
switch ($day) {
    case 'Monday': $day = "PONEDELJAK"; break;
    case 'Tuesday': $day = "UTORAK"; break;
    case 'Wednesday': $day = "SREDA"; break;
    case 'Thursday': $day = "ČETVRTAK"; break;
    case 'Friday': $day = "PETAK"; break;
    case 'Saturday': $day = "SUBOTA"; break;
    case 'Sunday': $day = "NEDELJA"; break;
}
$date = $day . ' - ' . date_format($date,"d. m. Y.");
echo $date;
```

Result - `PETAK - 14. 07. 2017.`

So, it works, but I suppose there is a shorter way, probably using `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'sr_BA')` but I'm not sure where to put it.

Any help?

Comment: You could switch on `date("l")` directly instead of creating a day and date variable.

Comment: `strftime` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

[strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) was DEPRECATED in PHP 8.1

You can use [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.formatobject.php):

```
$formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
    'sr_BA',
    \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    'Europe/Sarajevo' //more in: https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php
);

echo $formatter->formatObject(new \DateTime(), "eeee", "sr_BA");
```

- note that "eeee" is a format from [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) instead of `date_*()` function that will always returns name for days and months in english, also if you `setlocale()`, from documentation

> Format the time and/or date according to locale settings. Month and weekday names and other language-dependent strings respect the current locale set with setlocale().

Comment: Mind to explain why downvoting?

Comment: strftime is the correct answer, date does not take account of setLocale.

Answer (score 1):

Also my solution is to create an array for the days:
For example:
(you have to start the week with "NEDELJA" (sunday))

```
$daynames = array("NEDELJA", "PONEDELJAK", "UTORAK", "SREDA", "ČETVRTAK", "PETAK", "PETAK");

$dayW = date("w");
echo $daynames[$dayW]; // output "PETAK" (Friday)
```

Comment: Dear bonaca which one you took? I would like to see any accepted answer if I or @Fabio helped you.

Thank you.